# how to make ad appear in center of page?

Tags: jquery, css, ads

I would like to know how to make ad appear like in this site:
http://www.kraniem.lv/
Just dont click X otherwise ad will close and will be visible only next day again.

Comment: Offtopic: I hope you know this is a really unwanted 'feature'. If I see this on a site I try to avoid that site in the future...

Comment: @PoweRoy I dont know if you succeeded to open the site, but it looks like this http://img508.imageshack.us/img508/1864/ss20110912135533.png and bothers you only once in a day,

Comment: I opened it, thats why I complained ;) Depending on the site content, it is possible you only want to see the page once a day. Thats means everytime closing the ad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Css:

```
#ad{
position: absolute; /* Or position:fixed; */
z-index: 2;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ad").css("top", (($(window).height() - $("#popup").outerHeight() ) / 2) + 'px');
    $("#ad").css("left",(($(window).width() - $("#popup").outerWidth() )/ 2 ) + 'px');
});
```

Please note that if you want to use images, you'll need to write it as:

```
$("#ad").css("top", (($(window).height() - $("#popup").outerHeight() - imgheight) / 2) + 'px');
```

because basically, the image loads after the document dom was loaded, so I usually parse the image height as one of the attributes, so I'll know what to subtract.

Please note that the link didn't work for me, so I'm just writing based on prior works I did.

Edit:
to make a **UI screen block**:

CSS:

```
#blanket{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
opacity:0.7;
z-index:1;
width: 100%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#blanket").css("height", $(document).height() + 'px');
```

HTML:

```
<div id="blanket"></div>
<div id="popup"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, you can check the screenshot here, dont know why its not working for you: http://img508.imageshack.us/img508/1864/ss20110912135533.png

Comment: you'll need to add some sort of a button to close it, read on jquery: hide(), and to display once a day - you'll need to use a cookie...